# Can't get rid of unwanted output when web scraping

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm having problem with web scraping. I need to extract name and date from a website and I found one way how to locate it but I have unwanted output (.text doesn't work). My code:

```
wanted_name = 'clear'
link = f'https://namemc.com/name/{wanted_name}'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36'
}

html_text = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text.text, 'lxml')
names = []
_dates = []

users = soup.find('div', class_='col-md-7')
for user in users:
    names.append(user.find('samp'))

dates = soup.find('div', class_='row no-gutters align-items-center')
for time in dates:
    _dates.append(time.find('time'))
```

Output:

```
[-1, <samp>clear</samp>, -1, None, -1]
[-1, None, -1, None, -1, <time class="text-nowrap" datetime="2021-03-22T17:06:03.000Z" id="availability-time"></time>, -1, None, -1
```

Is there any way how to output the username `clear` and the date `2021-03-22T17:06:03.000Z`?

link: https://namemc.com/name/clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting more values than needed. If you go deeper in your users and dates like this:

```
users = soup.find('div', class_='col-md-7').find('samp') 
for user in users:
    names.append(user)

dates = soup.find('div', class_='row no-gutters align-items-center').find('time')
_dates.append(dates['datetime'])
```

Then you get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`user.find('samp').getText()` would give you the username `clear`.

`time.find('time')["datetime]` would give you `2021-03-22T17:06:03.000Z`. Be sure to handle errors of **None**, **-1**

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to return the value and select for a shared parent. Then select desired items from that.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_users(wanted_name):
    url = f'https://namemc.com/name/{wanted_name}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    node = soup.select_one(f".card-body .row:has(a[href*='{wanted_name}'])")
    print(node.select_one('a').text)
    print(node.select_one('time').text)
    
get_users('Clear')
```